# Get elapsed from log table

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-11g

From a log table with a row for every column changed in another table I need to get the elapsed time between two complex event.

In particular the log table has the format

```
create table audit_log as
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4210 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/04 12:06:03', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Status' ap_property_name, null AP_OLD_VALUE, 'New' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4212 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/04 14:31:22', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Status' ap_property_name, 'New' AP_OLD_VALUE, 'Open' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4212 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/04 14:31:22', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Resolver Group' ap_property_name, null AP_OLD_VALUE, 'rg-cro-contabilita' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4213 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/04 14:32:22', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Resolver Group' ap_property_name, 'rg-cro-contabilita' AP_OLD_VALUE, 'rg-cro-configuration' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4241 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/06 09:31:47', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Resolver Group' ap_property_name, 'rg-cro-configuration' AP_OLD_VALUE, 'rg-cro-integration' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4318 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/10 16:27:02', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Status' ap_property_name, 'Open'  AP_OLD_VALUE, 'Assigned' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4319 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/10 16:27:16', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Status' ap_property_name, 'Assigned' AP_OLD_VALUE, 'In Progress' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4320 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/10 16:28:20', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Status' ap_property_name, 'In Progress' AP_OLD_VALUE, 'Rejected' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual union
select 10 AU_ENTITY_ID, 4326 AU_ACTION_ID, TO_DATE('2016/05/10 17:26:53', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AU_TIME, 'Status' ap_property_name, 'Rejected' AP_OLD_VALUE, 'Closed' AP_NEW_VALUE FROM dual
```

The expected result is something like

```
|AU_ENTITY_ID|AU_TIME  |TIME_OLD |   ELAPSED|ELAPSED_BUSINESSDAY|STATUS_OLD_HISTORY|STATUS_NEW_HISTORY|RG_OLD_HISTORY      |RG_NEW_HISTORY    |
|-----------:|:--------|:--------|---------:|------------------:|:-----------------|:-----------------|:-------------------|:-----------------|
|          10|06-MAY-16|04-MAY-16|   1.79126|            1.79126|Open              |Open              |rg-cro-configuration|rg-cro-integration|
|          10|10-MAY-16|06-MAY-16|   4.28836|            2.28836|Open              |Assigned          |rg-cro-integration  |rg-cro-integration|
|          10|10-MAY-16|10-MAY-16|.000162037|         .000162037|Assigned          |In Progress       |rg-cro-integration  |rg-cro-integration|
|          10|10-MAY-16|10-MAY-16|.000740740|         .000740740|In Progress       |Rejected          |rg-cro-integration  |rg-cro-integration|
```

The query is for a report system that can execute a single select, it expect `SELECT` as the first word, that mean I cannot use any CTE

I came up with this query, but it seems a little to much

```
SELECT AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME
     , Time_Old
     , Elapsed
     , Elapsed - (floor((Elapsed + 0 + Time_Old_WeekDay) / 7)) - (floor((Elapsed + 1 + Time_Old_WeekDay) / 7)) ELAPSED_BUSINESSDAY
     , Status_Old_History
     , Status_New_History
     , RG_Old_History
     , RG_New_History
FROM   (SELECT AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME
             , Time_Old
             , 1 + TRUNC(Time_Old) - TRUNC (Time_Old, 'IW') Time_Old_WeekDay
             , AU_TIME - Time_Old Elapsed
             , LAST_VALUE(Status_Old_History IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY AU_ENTITY_ID ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) Status_Old_History
             , LAST_VALUE(Status_New_History IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY AU_ENTITY_ID ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) Status_New_History
             , LAST_VALUE(RG_Old_History IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY AU_ENTITY_ID ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) RG_Old_History
             , LAST_VALUE(RG_New_History IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY AU_ENTITY_ID ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) RG_New_History
        FROM (SELECT AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME
                   , LAG(AU_TIME, 1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY AU_ENTITY_ID ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME) Time_Old
                   , DECODE(Status_Old_History, '', LAG(Status_New_History, 1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY AU_ENTITY_ID ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME), Status_Old_History) Status_Old_History
                   , Status_New_History
                   , DECODE(RG_Old_History, '', LAG(RG_New_History, 1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY AU_ENTITY_ID ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME), RG_Old_History) RG_Old_History
                   , RG_New_History
              FROM   (SELECT AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME
                           , MAX(DECODE(AP_PROPERTY_NAME, 'Status', AP_OLD_VALUE, null)) Status_Old_History
                           , MAX(DECODE(AP_PROPERTY_NAME, 'Status', AP_NEW_VALUE, null)) Status_New_History
                           , MAX(DECODE(AP_PROPERTY_NAME, 'Resolver Group', AP_OLD_VALUE, null)) RG_Old_History
                           , MAX(DECODE(AP_PROPERTY_NAME, 'Resolver Group', AP_NEW_VALUE, null)) RG_New_History
                      FROM   audit_log AL
                      WHERE  1 = 1
                        AND  au_entity_type = 'BUG'
                        AND  ap_property_name IN ('Status', 'Resolver Group')
                      GROUP BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME, AP_ACTION_ID
                      UNION
                      SELECT AU_ENTITY_ID, sysdate
                           , null Status_Old_History, 'current' Status_New_History
                           , null RG_Old_History, null RG_New_History
                      FROM   audit_log
                      WHERE  1 = 1
                        AND  au_entity_type = 'BUG') data
              ) History
       ) Full_History
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND Status_Old_History IN ('Open', 'Assigned', 'In Progress')
  AND RG_Old_History IN ('rg-cro-configuration', 'rg-cro-integration', 'rg-cro-contabilità', 'rg-cro-migration')
ORDER BY AU_ENTITY_ID, AU_TIME
```

Now I'm trying to slim it down or redesign to be easier to manage.

Any ideas?